# Inline set property of JS Object only if value is defined

Tags: javascript, firebase, object, firebase-realtime-database, properties

### Situation

I'm currently writing constructors for pushing data to the database.

One of those constructors looks like this:

```js
/**
 * Timestamp
 *
 * @constructor
 */
function Timestamp() {
 this.timestamp = new Date().getTime();
 this.date = new Date().toUTCString();
}

/**
 * @param {string}    [parameters.status]
 * @param {Timestamp} [parameters.sent]
 * @param {Timestamp} [parameters.delivered]
 * @constructor
 */
function Shipping(parameters) {
 const { status, sent, delivered } = parameters;
 this.status                       = status;
 this.timestamps                   = {
  sent:      sent,
  delivered: delivered
 };
}

console.log(new Shipping({
 status: "pending",
 delivered: new Timestamp()
}));
```

The backend updates **all** values which are set (I'm using Firebase Database).

In this example there are 2 timestamps

1. sent - represents the timestamp when the shipment has been sent
2. delivered - represents the timestamp when the shipment arrived

In the scenario above the shipment has been dispatched already some time ago. The function to update the database has been called because the shipment arrived. We **only** want to update the `delivered` timestamp and **not** the `sent` timestamp.

Firebase on the other hand is really sensitive to overwriting data related to updates. If we were to use the code above we would set the `sent` timestamp to `undefined` which would erase the timestamp from the database. So we mustn't set the value for `sent` at all.

---

### Problem

I could write out functions inside of the constructor to test against `undefined`. That works but it is not pretty and not easy to maintain. Especially when considering the huge database structure (the example above does not show not the whole extend).

The code for that might look similar to that (**This code works**):

```js
/**
 * Timestamp
 *
 * @constructor
 */
function Timestamp() {
 this.timestamp = new Date().getTime();
 this.date = new Date().toUTCString();
}

/**
 * @param {string}    [parameters.status]
 * @param {Timestamp} [parameters.sent]
 * @param {Timestamp} [parameters.delivered]
 * @constructor
 */
function Shipping(parameters) {
 const { status, sent, delivered } = parameters;
 if (status !== undefined) this.status = status;
 this.timestamps = {};
 if (sent !== undefined) this.timestamps.sent = sent;
 if (delivered !== undefined) this.timestamps.delivered = delivered;
}

console.log(new Shipping({
 status:    "pending",
 delivered: new Timestamp()
}));
```

---

### My solution idea

The best "pseudo" approach to this problem I can think of is using inline tests using the OR-operator. Be aware that this **won't work** because at least from my experience `null` as well as `undefined` do **overwrite** firebase data.

Instead we "**don't even want to touch**" the data.

Here is the solution **if** `null` would **not overwrite** data in firebase:

```js
/**
 * Timestamp
 *
 * @constructor
 */
function Timestamp() {
 this.timestamp = new Date().getTime();
 this.date = new Date().toUTCString();
}

/**
 * @param {string}    [parameters.status]
 * @param {Timestamp} [parameters.sent]
 * @param {Timestamp} [parameters.delivered]
 * @constructor
 */
function Shipping(parameters) {
 const { status, sent, delivered } = parameters;
 this.status                       = status || null;
 this.timestamps                   = {
  sent:      sent || null,
  delivered: delivered || null
 };
}

console.log(new Shipping({
 status:    "pending",
 delivered: new Timestamp()
}));
```

---

**How can I only set a value of a JS object if it contains a value?**

---

### Solution

Thank you [Jonas W.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5260024/jonas-w) for your solution!

Working code:

```js
/**
 * Timestamp
 *
 * @constructor
 */
function Timestamp() {
 this.timestamp = new Date().getTime();
 this.date = new Date().toUTCString();
}

/**
 * Remove all nested keys with value "undefined" in an object
 * @param object
 */
function clean(object) {
 Object.keys(object).forEach(key => {
  if (object[key] && typeof object[key] === "object") {
   // Iterate through nested keys
   clean(object[key]);
  } else if (object[key] === undefined) {
   // Found a value which is undefined so we'll remove its key
   delete object[key];
  }
 });
}

/**
 * @param {string}    [parameters.status]
 * @param {Timestamp} [parameters.sent]
 * @param {Timestamp} [parameters.delivered]
 * @constructor
 */
function Shipping(parameters) {
 const { status, sent, delivered } = parameters;
 this.status                       = status;
 this.timestamps                   = {
  sent:      sent,
  delivered: delivered
 };
 clean(this);
}

console.log(new Shipping({
 status:    "pending",
 delivered: new Timestamp()
}));
```

**How it works**

Before finishing the constructor we execute the `clean()` function which deletes all keys with the value `undefined`. You can also modify the clean() function to test against other values. For example you could have this function to remove all keys with the value `"remove me"`:

```
/**
 * Remove all nested keys with value "remove me" in an object
 * @param object
 */
function clean(object) {
    Object.keys(object).forEach(key => {
        if (object[key] && typeof object[key] === "object") {
            // Iterate through nested keys
            clean(object[key]);
        } else if (object[key] === "remove me") {
            // Found a value which is equal to "remove me" so we'll remove its key
            delete object[key];
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could clear the undefineds from the object:

```
for(const key in obj)
  if(obj[key] === undefined)
    delete obj[key];
```

That could be done in the constructor or when sending to database.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function Shipping(parameters) {
    const timestamps = Object.keys(parameters)
    .reduce((acc, key) => {
       if (parameters[key] !== undefined) acc[key] = parameters[key];
       return acc;
    }, {});
    console.log(timestamps);
}

Shipping({
    status: 'pending',
    delivered: '26/02/2018',
    sent: undefined
})
```

Comment: @JonasW. thanks for pointing out this edge case. I updated my answer